# Iterating through StaticResource loaded by ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Given a resource dictionary loading some static resources into memory - is there any way to iterate through theResources loaded into memory?  My silverlight application keeps telling me it cannot find a static resource.  I wonder if I have a naming convention issue or somehting - was hoping iterating through the resources in memory would help diagnose any issue...

I have the following app.xaml

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             x:Class="Module1.MyApp">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/FSSilverlightApp;component/TransitioningFrame.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and content template:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"  
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="TransitioningFrame" TargetType="navigation:Frame">
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
            <ContentPresenter Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources defined in Application.Resources are implicitly available to all controls in the app, not sure about merged dictionaries. You can set a breakpoint in a control constructor and inspect `this.Resources`, `this.Resources.MergedDictionaries`, `Application.Resources` and `Application.Resources.MergedDictionaries` to see if your resource is there.

Also try to put the merged dictionaries in your control, see if that makes any difference:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/FSSilverlightApp;component/TransitioningFrame.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<!--Use the style later in the same file-->
<navigation:Frame Style={StaticResource TransitioningFrame} />
```

Comment: hmmm.  adding the dictionary to the UserControl.Resources - seems to make everything work...  Why do you think that would be?  When the reference was in the app.xaml only I was able to get a refernece to the element via:

let i2 : ControlTemplate = downcast Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.[0].["TransitioningFrame"]

Which shows it is loaded - but the app still threw the exception

Comment: Not sure, perhaps a some kind of circular dependency throwing the spanner in the works? Maybe you can test whether or not this is your component that's having issues by placing a simple resource, like a Brush, in the merged dictionary and seeing if it's available in the control?

Comment: absolutley I can muck around with it. But I think I have enough of this done, where I can pass it off to an engineer to pump some dummy tables etc in place for a demo.  Having this app in 100% f# hasn't been easy - but thank you for helping me iron down one of the last "functional" unknowns.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the choice of XAML/F#?

Comment: I like the brevity of the F# language and find it very expressive.  I am gonig to have my algo's and intelligence team switch to coding primarily in F# (as opposed to a mixture of Tsql / R /Matlab), and my services and infrastructure team as well.  But that usage of F# is pretty well studied.  I also wanted to see if I had the patience to code this app with so little knowledge of SIlverilght and only a primitive knowledge of F#. I learned alot in the process about thinks like: the relationship between XAML and the "codebehind" etc.  It was fun